# Java how to take chars as an argument and then the method prints the sequence forwards and backwards?

Tags: java

I am working on a problem: take a sequence of any characters as an argument to a method and then the method needs to take them and print out the same sequence forwards and backwards.

My problem is I am confused by the characters. I understand how to do this with int, or String, but I don't understand how to do it with chars. My thoughts were could I use a buffer, or maybe a collection list? I'm just looking for some pointers to lead me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: What does "*sequence of characters*" mean in Java terms?

Comment: "sequence of characters" doesn't mean string?

Answer (score 1):

"a sequence of any characters" seems very vague to me.

- `"Hello"` resembles a sequence of characters as a `String`
- `"Hello".toCharArray()` resembles a sequence of characters as a `char[]`
- `123456` resembles a sequence of characters as an `int`

Having said that, an approach to this could go in many different directions.  This approach addresses the 3 examples I've listed using overloaded methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    reverse("Hello");
    reverse("Racecar".toCharArray()); // Palindrome
    reverse(123456);
}

// Add more overloads for other data types

public static void reverse(int ints) {
    reverse(String.valueOf(ints));
}

public static void reverse(char[] chars) {
    reverse(new String(chars));
}

public static void reverse(CharSequence chars) {
    System.out.println(chars);
    System.out.println(new StringBuffer(chars).reverse());
}
```

Results:

```
Hello
olleH
Racecar
racecaR
123456
654321
```